# Converter uma data e enviar ao banco

Tags: java, mysql, data

O codigo está todo funcionando, o problema é a data, quero pegar a data de um jformatedtextfiel ##/##/#### no caso txt_data e enviar ao banco, estou no basico de java, estou enganchado nesse codigo há dias e pesquisei muito mas não chegei a um resultado. Por favor se alguem puder ajudar agradeço.

```
con_cliente.conecta();
    Date data;
    SimpleDateFormat in = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");//do sistema para o banco
    String dataformatada = in.format(txt_data.getText());
        try{
            data = in.parse(dataformatada);
            String gry = "insert into cadastrodeprocesso (Datadecadastro, Cliente, Classificacao, Usuario) values ('"+
                            data.getDate()+"','"+
                            txt_nome.getText()+"','"+
                            cb_classificacao.getSelectedItem()+"','"+
                            txt_usuario.getText()+"')";
                            con_cliente.exeQuery(gry);
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Gravado com sucesso!");   
            } catch(Exception add){
                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Falha ao gravar o registro " +add);
            }
    }//area para impossibilitar duplicar cadastros de empresas de mesmo nome
    else{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Clique em novo para inserir um novo registro");
    return;
    }
    }
```

}

Comment: Perguntas: dá algum erro, se sim, qual? Qual o tipo do campo Datadecadastro na sua tabela?

Comment: Acho que isto já foi respondido por aqui inúmeras vezes.

Comment: eu pesquisei mas não achei aqui.

Comment: o campo é do tipo date,

Answer (score 1):

Se no seu textfield a data está no formato dd/MM/yyyy, então você deve construir um objeto do tipo SimpleDateFormat com esse formato, assim:

```
SimpleDateFormat in = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Feito isso, você utiliza o método *parse* da SimpleDateFormat para, a partir de um input em String, obter um objeto do tipo Date.

```
Date data = in.parse(txt_data.getText());
```

A partir daí, é gravar no banco de dados. Entretanto, note que a sua coluna Datadecadastro deve ser do tipo Date (ou DateTime, nao conheco MySQL), caso contrário pode dar problema.

Enfim, você não precisa utilizar o método *format* da SimpleDateFormat. Este método é para, a partir de um objeto do tipo Date, obter uma String formatada.

Comment: sim a coluna esta como date, infelizmente gerou um erro java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "05/08/2015"

Comment: 05/08/2015 é o valor que está no seu TextField? Veja esse Ideone que fiz para você testar: http://ideone.com/wBtE5t O mês é impresso com 1 a menos, pois na classe Calendar ele começa de 0.

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado pessoal, consegui resolver com a ajuda do colega **cantoni**

```
SimpleDateFormat in = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

Date data = in.parse(txt_data.getText());
```

A unica coisa que inseri para converter em que faltou foi

```
String str = txt_data.getText();
```

e depois eu dei um insert e viva

```
con_cliente.conecta();
        try{
            SimpleDateFormat formatador = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");  
            String str = txt_data.getText();  
            Date data = formatador.parse(str);
            String gry = "insert into cadastrodeprocesso (Datadecadastro, Cliente, Classificacao, Usuario) values ('"+
                            new java.sql.Date(data.getTime())+"','"+
                            txt_nome.getText()+"','"+
                            cb_classificacao.getSelectedItem()+"','"+
                            txt_usuario.getText()+"')";
                            con_cliente.exeQuery(gry);
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Gravado com sucesso!");   
            } catch(Exception add){
                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Falha ao gravar o registro " +add);
            }
    }
```

Comment: Olá @user28748, nesse caso, você não precisa responder a sua própria pergunta, já que outra resposta te ajudou. Funciona assim: se uma resposta te ajudou com a sua pergunta, aceite-a como a correta. Esse é o sinal que você dá para outros informando que o seu problema foi resolvido baseado na resposta aceita. Isso ajuda a quem tiver a mesma dúvida ou uma dúvida semelhante no futuro.

Comment: Note que não há nada de mal em você mesmo responder a sua pergunta. Mas isso você só faz se outra resposta não resolver o seu problema. Caso a resposta tenha resolvido parcialmente, inclua um comentário para que o autor da resposta complete-a. Assim, a resposta pode servir para mais pessoas.